# Building Xalan for iOS (armv7/armv7s) platform

Tags: c++, ios, cross-compiling, armv7, xalan

Has anybody successful cross compiled the Xalan C++ library for armv7/armv7s arch to be used on iOS device (not simulator)?
I was able to cross compile the xerces library by setting the iOS g++/gcc compilers for armv7 but using the same procedure for Xalan gives me below error while running the make file:

```
iComp:c iComp$ make 
Linux, Solaris, AIX, Compaq Tru64, OS/390, MacOSX, HP-UX, NETBSD, FREEBSD, CYGWIN, and MINGW are the only platforms supported.
```

Above error clearly states that I cannot target the iOS platform.
So was there some problem in configuring the makefiles?

### UPDATE

The above issue was occurring because of incorrect usage of Xalan's runConfigure file.
The correct usage to pass additional options to Configure file via runConfigure is to use '-C' option with "--host=arm-apple-darwin --disable-shared"

This has helped to resolve the above platform detection issue and generated the cross-compile make files.

## PROBLEM

But now the issue is while running the make, default MsgLoader (inmeme)executable is generated (target: armv7) and after that the make file tries to run the armv7 executable on Mac OSX obviously giving the error **'Bad CpuType in executable'**

How can I either avoid the building of Xalan by creating a armv7 exe of MsgLoader or run this armv7 exe in terminal (doesn't seems possible!) so that it proceeds with the build.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: _"Above error clearly states that I cannot target the armv7 arch"_ - no, it says you cannot target **the iOS platform**. It says nothing about architecture. As it happens, given a supported platform, [the architecture is clearly not an issue](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/armhf/xalan/filelist).

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes you are right. Sorry my bad! But the issue is I want to target it for iOS platform. If xerces is allowing this why can't Xalan.